# jQuery chat application spam

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax -> PHP simple chat and I want to stop users from sending too many chat requests, or messages too quickly. What is a good way to limit the amount of messages any one user can send so as to avoid spamming. I have done the normal checks for nulls, and white space messages. I am looking for a way to prevent users from sending multiple messages back to back, like constantly pressing the send button or pressing enter. I want to limit this action to 1 message per 5 seconds, or if the user sends too many questions within a 5 second period to force a waiting period before being able to send another message.

Comment: you probably need to store chat requests somewhere database or session.

Answer (score 2):

I feel the threshhold per minute approach would be better than setting a constant time delay for each message.  This would feel more natural.

If implemented in JS on the client side, it'd be smart to also check the rate on the server side as well and return an error code if the rate is exceeded. In case someone tries to exploit the AJAX endpoint by flooding it with requests, but you could also implement some kind of CSRF strategy to avoid that exploit scenario.

Comment: I would prefer an approach like this also, but how do I keep this threshold per minute with JS?

Comment: use `window.setInterval` and every time an AJAX request is, keep a running tally in a global variable.  You could use the interval to knock these tallies back to 0 every minute or so.  If you have multiple chat windows, you could keep an array with tallies for each active chat window.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to handle this would be to start a timer after a new chat message is sent, then disable chat message submission until that timer reaches a certain number (e.g. 5 seconds, 15 seconds, 30 seconds). You could visually indicate this to the user by disabling and greying out the "Send" button.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a time delay: a user can't post to chat more than 15 times in a minute.